# Distribute the iteration in a column in particular array with min and max

Tags: arrays, loops, excel-formula, simulation, calculated-columns

**How to distribute cell value in column with specific number using excel formula?**

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer,

In showing the right distribution of a sum in a column with min and max in the iteration.

Simulation :

Have a condition if (column (A1 = A0)) 
then add another condition if (column (A1 = A2), possible answer to look for the sum of the min and max less to the total array. (We assume that min and max amount is disregarded to the array before distributing the less).
then shows min else max
else min.

Hope this helps.